# Resizing Background on ipad/tablet

Tags: android, html, ios, css, background

All currently developing this forum/site:

http://nfldynasty.boards.net/

Lots to finish in terms of content, however I'm currently having some problems resizing the various backgrounds on mobile devices such as ipad and Samsung android tablet etc.

All seems to work well when viewing on laptop via both google chrome and internet explorer.

The code I'm using is as follows

```
body {
-webkit-background-size: cover;
    -ms-background-size: cover;
   -moz-background-size: cover;
     -o-background-size: cover;
        background-size: cover;    
}
html { height: 100%; width: 100%; }
```

I cannot seem to work out a way of adjusting the background size on ipad/tablet etc without either changing this on internet explorer to changing the size of the text boxes. i.e. when I change the html tab from 100% to say 75% the background remains unaltered but the size of the forum categories reduces

If I remover the final html line then on all devices the image is distorted when zooming in and out on the text.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this for smaller screens:

```
body {
    background-color: #000;
    background-size: contain;
    background-position: center top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Nora, thanks for the reply but unfortunately it does not seem to fix the issue